# MicroBlaze: how to see application messages through JTAG link after application burn

Tags: terminal, console, jtag, microblaze

I use Xilinx Software Development Kit (SDK) 14.7, based on Eclipse to create, run and debug application for MicroBlaze microprocessor. When I load my application (SDK/Run) I see application's printf messages on SDK Console through JTAG-UART USB connection.

I use Xilinx Platform Cable USB II (model DLC10).

**Question**: How to see application messages after I burn Xilinx FPGA with FPGA+MicroBlaze code. SDK Console does not show them.

In other words I look for "nios2-terminal" for MicroBlaze if use Altera Nios terminology.

Answer (score 0):

If you added the UART IP Core, you can use anything - Putty, Terminal v1.9, Tera Term, etc., check here https://reference.digilentinc.com/vivado/getting-started-with-ipi/start

Comment: I'am a SW designer and no HW one. Our product design has no free UART for maintenance and has no additional material UART connector. However our product has JTAG port that is almost not in use. JTAG port, when working with SDK, YES is used for printf-s messages. As why do not use it for functionality I asked in my post? More of then, Nios II of Altera, that is analog of Xilinx MicroBlaze, has such JTAG-port functionality that I look for and ask here!!!

Comment: Okay, got you, have you tried this? https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/66370.html

Comment: Yes, I did. Disadvantage of this solution is that the connection to JTAG terminal possible only after MicroBlaze starts. It means that all messages that commonly appear on power up of microprocessor (x initialization finished... fw version 4.5.6 ... etc)  can not be shown.

Comment: well, AFAIK, nios2-terminal has the same disadvantage
do you need this information in console?

Comment: Daniil, nios2-terminal works perfectly. When I run the terminal even 10 minutes after Nios II processor powered-up, I see all power-up log of the Nios. Such is in my configuration (Altera Arria 10, Quartus 15.1)